# JWT Issue: What is the best way to store multiple tokens in the database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

I'm having trouble storing the refreshToken on the database when I login to another browser, the refreshToken gets replaced resulting in my current browser being logged out. So what is the best solution to save multiple refreshToken? Or am I misunderstanding it, please help me!!!

Comment: What is your table schema in which you are saving your refresh token

Comment: Store both refresh tokens?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.